# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I want to add conditional for image but it show an error on `_setImage()`, how to fix it?

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'String', is a potentially non-nullable type.
> Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

```
  class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
      final String appName = AppConfig.appName;
    
      String _setImage() {
      if(appName.isNotEmpty == '') {
        return 'assets/something1.png';
      } else if(appName.isNotEmpty == '') {
        return 'assets/something2.png';
      } 
      }
     
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: AssetImage(_setImage()) //call your method here
                ),
              ),
            );
      }
    }
```

Comment: The condition of this code have a fundamental problem. The response of the inNotEmpty method is a boolean, and you are checking it with a String, which will always be false. And in result you will get null.

Answer (score 1):

appName.isNotEmpty is already a condition.

Change your code like this :

```
 if(appName.isNotEmpty) {
   return 'assets/something1.png';
 } 

 return 'assets/something2.png';
```

Comment: im already try it with those before i add it with isNotEmpty, it still showing the same error

Comment: Have you alredy add the images to the assets in pubspec.yaml ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because appName.isNotEmpty is already a condition.

To fix:

```
String _setImage() {
  if(appName.isNotEmpty) {
    return 'assets/something1.png';
  } else {
    return 'assets/something2.png';
  } 
}
```

Comment: im already try it with those before i add it with isNotEmpty, it still showing the same error

Comment: can u show me the full code of that file

Answer (score 1):

isNotEmpty is a getter and returns a boolean value that's why you can simply call it without adding further condition to it.

```
String _setImage() { 
           return appName != null && appName.isNotEmpty ? 'assets/something1.png' : 'assets/something2.png';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest of all the answer is try to add default return,

```
  String _setImage() {
      if(appName.isNotEmpty == '') {
        return 'assets/something1.png';
      } else if(appName.isNotEmpty == '') {
        return 'assets/something2.png';
      } 
       return 'assets/default.png';  This needs to be added
      }
```

---

##### Why are you facing this error ?

Because your return type is `String` and you are returning `String` only if `appName.isNotEmpty == ''` in your first if and `appName.isNotEmpty == ''` in your second if.

What if `appName.isNotEmpty == ''` condition is not met? so you need to have a default return .

---

##### Recommendation:

Your second else if is not necessary, change your code to :

```
  String _setImage() {
      if(appName.isNotEmpty == '') {
        return 'assets/something1.png';
      return 'assets/something2.png';  This is the best possible solution
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is showing this error because your function's **return type is String** which is **non-nullable**.

You have't write the code for if neither of your conditions gets true then what to return.

Following are two solutions for it.

1. Try to make _setImage()'s **return a nullable String**. So function's return type should be **String?** Like following code snippet.

   ```dart
     String? _setImage() {
         if(appName.isNotEmpty == '') {
           return 'assets/something1.png';
         } else if(appName.isNotEmpty == '') {
           return 'assets/something2.png';
        } 
     }
   ```

   **OR**
2. Return a **String** at every place where your function can possibly return.

   ```dart
    String _setImage() {
             if(appName.isNotEmpty == '') {
               return 'assets/something1.png';
             }
            return 'assets/something3.png'; //Default image if neither of the conditions gets satisfied.
         }
   ```

However, I recommend you to use this package [another_flutter_splash_screen 1.1.4](https://pub.dev/packages/another_flutter_splash_screen) as it is highly customizable for splash screens.